# Unable to create a session via CouchBase sync gateway admin REST API

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am working on implementing custom authentication using cookie Auth. So, I was playing around the sync gateway REST API to create user and session. I could successfully create the user but unable to create session via /_session API. 
Following are the steps I followed.

**1. Create user**

```
POST /cookbook/_user/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4985
Content-Type: application/json
{
"name": "chef123",
"password": "1234"
}
```

**2. Get Users**

```
GET /cookbook/_user/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4985
Content-Type: application/json

Respone :["chef123"]
```

**3. Create Session**

```
  POST /cookbook/_session HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:59840
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
        "name": "chef123",
        "ttl": 1800
    }

Expected:
{
    "cookie_name": "SyncGatewaySession", 
    "expires": "2014-11-07T16:42:11.675519255-08:00", 
    "session_id": "c2425fa7d734bc8c3f6c507854166bef56a5fbc6"
}

Instead received:
{"authentication_handlers":["default","cookie"],"ok":true,"userCtx":{"channels":{},"name":null}}
```

Can Anyone please explain why is the API giving the following response.

***{"authentication_handlers":["default","cookie"],"ok":true,"userCtx":{"channels":{},"name":null}}***

Comment: is your problem solved.  I am having the same issue.

Comment: for the the problem was "/" at the end of the request URL. I tried http://localhost:4985/db/_session instead of http://localhost:4985/db/_session// and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`authentication_handlers` is the method you used to create the session (it could be the built-in facebook or persona login features as well). `userCtx` has useful information on the data access for this user like:

- `channels`: The channels the user was given access to via the Sync Function
- `admin_channels`: The channels the user was given access to in the config file
- `roles`: The roles of this user

See the session docs for details: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/references/sync-gateway/admin-rest-api/session-admin/get-db-session-sessionid/index.html

To set up authentication with Sync Gateway you can check those blogs:

- [Adding user Sign Up to your Android app with Node.js and Couchbase Mobile](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/september/adding-user-sign-up-to-your-android-app-with-node.js-and-couchbase-mobile)
- [Adding Google Sign-In with Node.js to a Couchbase Mobile application](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/october/adding-google-sign-in-with-node.js-to-a-couchbase-mobile-application)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [krishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596530/krishnan), the solution to this problem is removing the trailing slash from the URI. I had the same issue.

So, instead of: `POST /cookbook/_session/`

Use: `POST /cookbook/_session`